# match a string with special char and exact match using grep

Tags: grep

I have a large file and want to search only specific string. 
eg. `mobNo='xxx-xxx-xxxx'`  i have a lot of string in this formate.

i am tring `grep "mobNo=\'*\'"` . can some one help  me. Thanks in advance.

#### Update #1

I tried `grep "mobNo='[^']*'"` file and `grep -io "mobNo='[^']*'"` file also, both are not giving any result.

Comment: Regarding update #1, both forms of the command work for me using a file I created by cutting and pasting from your question.  Can you cut and paste a sample from the test file that you are using and put it in the question?  (Do a cut-and-paste, __do not retype__.)  Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes do not need to be escaped when they are inside double quotes:

```
grep "mobNo='[^']*'" file
```

Also, `grep` uses regular expressions, not shell patterns (globs).  In the shell, `*` matches zero or more of any character at all.  In a regex, however, `*` matches zero or more of the preceding character.  Here we use `[^']*` which means zero of more of any character that is not a single quote.